# Null pointer access: The variable nodeptr can only be null at this location

Tags: java, eclipse, pointers, null

I have this code When I run it I get the error:

```
"Null pointer access: The variable nodeptr can only be null at this location"


static class point {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
    }

    static class problem {
            point[] nodeptr; 
    }
public static Tsp.point[] as_P_F()
    {

    Tsp.point[] nodeptr = null;


        for(int i=0;i<Input.General_Inputs.N;i++){
        nodeptr[i] = new Tsp.point();
        nodeptr[i].x = p[i];
        nodeptr[i].y = C[i];
        nodeptr[i].z = L[i];
        }

    return (nodeptr);
    }
```

I think the error was because I defined  Tsp.point[] nodeptr as null so I did the following code:

```
public static Tsp.point[] as_P_F()
   {

    Tsp.point[] nodeptr = new Tsp.point[Input.General_Inputs.N];


        for(int i=0;i<Input.General_Inputs.N;i++){
        //nodeptr[i] = new Tsp.point();
        nodeptr[i].x = P[i];
        nodeptr[i].y = C[i];
        nodeptr[i].z = L[i];
        }

    return (nodeptr);
    }
```

But I am not sure if this right or not this is my first time using this concept I tried to search on the net but I didn't find anything useful. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize both the array and idividual `Tsp.point` elements of the array :

```
    Tsp.point[] nodeptr = new Tsp.point[Input.General_Inputs.N];

    for(int i=0;i<Input.General_Inputs.N_O_P;i++){
      nodeptr[i] = new Tsp.point();
      nodeptr[i].x = P[i];
      nodeptr[i].y = C[i];
      nodeptr[i].z = L[i];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for Answering but can you explain please why I need to initialize individual Tsp.point elements of the array. Sorry but this my first time I use this concept thanks

Comment: @robertjone `new Tsp.point[Input.General_Inputs.Num_Of_Ppes]` initializes the array, but each element of the array is initialized to null. Therefore you must assign an instance of `Tsp.point()` to each index of the array before you can access it.

Comment: one last question please do you know how I can call this method Tsp.point[] as_P_F()

Comment: Thanks Eran I really appreciate your response do you know how to convert Tsp.point[] nodeptr from point[] type to double[]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here :

```
public static Tsp.point[] assign_Pipe_Function()
    {

    Tsp.point[] nodeptr = null; // setting nodeptr to null. You have to initialize it with `new...`


        for(int i=0;i<Input.General_Inputs.Num_Of_Ppes;i++){
        nodeptr[i] = new Tsp.point();    // nodeptr is null so. nodeptr[i] will give NPE
        nodeptr[i].x = Pipe_Condition[i];
        nodeptr[i].y = Cof[i];
        nodeptr[i].z = Length[i];
        }

    return (nodeptr);
    }
```